# why exporting dataframe into aws mysql result in empty table?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to export my python dataframe into my mysql database. I have used the following code:

```
    database_username = 'user'
    database_password = '******'
    database_ip       = 'IP'
    database_name     = 'DBname'
    database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.
                                           format(database_username, database_password,
                                                  database_ip, database_name), pool_recycle=1, pool_timeout=57600).connect()

    df.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='fromMac', if_exists='append',chunksize=100)
    database_connection.close()
```

When checking the database in workbench I can find the new table created, but it is an empty table. I have checked the dataframe it is not empty. I don't know what is causing this.